# How to avoid game crash when entering Canyon of Titans in Wasteland 2?

Tags: wasteland-2

When entering the Canyon of Titans Wasteland 2 suddenly freezes. Sometimes, I get to the script where Angela Deth leaves the party, yet often before or shortly afterwards, the game suddenly crashes.

This seems to be a bug. Yet is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the graphic option to the lowest possible settings, disabling the shadows, selecting the lowest possible texture size, disabling anti-alising, etc.

Then I could move around the Canyon of Titans and have as of yet not experienced a further crash.

Yet if you would talk to Jill Yates after healing the Doc, the chat window would freeze however, making any chat option unavailable. So until this is fixed, it is better not to talk to her again.

Comment: Not yet confirmed, but typing in "map" in the freezed chat window is supposed to pass the freezed chat window. (source: https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com//viewtopic.php?f=34&t=8644)

Comment: I haven't run into this at all, even after a marathon session.  Perhaps hardware related?

Comment: Are you running WL2 in 32bit mode? Then you're [running out of memory](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185820/wasteland-2-hangs-when-trying-to-enter-the-world-map) and reducing the graphics quality is indeed the only solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the graphic option to the lowest possible settings, disabling the shadows, selecting the lowest possible texture size, disabling anti-alising the game still crashed. 
At last I put motion blur off and the other settings back on normal or on and since no more crashes.