# Wasteland 2 freezes when trying to enter the world map

Tags: wasteland-2

In Wasteland 2, I'm trying to leave an area to enter the world map. The load screen appears and the progress bar starts updating but then stops. I can wait as long as I want, loading does not continue.

The progress is not always the same, it can go up to about 95% but still never completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this case is that Wasteland 2 runs out of memory when trying to load the world map. This is a known problem/limitation (see [thread from one of the WL2 developers](http://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/540734792847153053/)):

In this case, WL2 is running in 32bit mode and simply runs out of memory. There are two options to solve this:

- If there is a 64bit version available for your OS, run that. The Windows version supports 64bit, the Mac version does *not*. I don't know about Linux.
- Otherwise, we need to reduce the amount of memory used: you can do this by opening the *Options*, select the *Display* tab and in the *Overall Quality* drop-down box, select *Fastest*. I guess especially the option that reduces the texture size to 1/8th is what makes a difference here. The game should be able to load the world map again. You can then try to increase the quality until you run into the loading issue again and stay one level beyond the problematic quality.

In an [update on Kickstarter posted Oct. 1st 2014](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/inxile/wasteland-2/posts/1003934), inXile wrote:

> We are also hard at work fixing memory-related issues to reduce crashes on 32-bit machines.

Answer (score 0):

Got almost the same issue on linux, and there is a solution that works perfect:

```
Open /etc/security/limits.conf as root and paste the the following two 
lines and replace "username" with your user name or with * for all 
users and reboot afterwards.

username soft nofile 4096
username hard nofile 8192
```